# Mysql - Does INSERT IGNORE that fails gets replicated to slave?

Tags: mysql, insert, database-replication

I am wondering if i execute an `INSERT IGNORE` query that fails (Due to key collision), does it get replicated to the slave to be executed there as well, or only if the query passes?

Thanks

Comment: Which kind of replication? Binary or statement?

Answer (score 2):

The `INSERT IGNORE` query does not fail - it does not insert the records which do not colide, and returns successfully. This means that the new inserted records should be replicated.

> a successful execution of “replace into” or “insert ignore” on the
>   master maps to a normal insertion on the slave

This means that only the rows that are inserted on the master will be replicated, and the ones ignored by the master won't be replicated on the slave, even if the slave doesn't have them.

[Some information on the topic @ tokutek](http://www.tokutek.com/2010/08/on-replace-into-insert-ignore-triggers-and-row-based-replication/)